# What is a Closely Capital Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a phrase conforms to a special rule, I call it a Closely Capital Phrase™.  Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Closely Capital Phrases™ | Not Closely Capital Phrases™ |
| --- | --- |
| BEARD COM | MUSTACHE DRAMA |
| BRAKE LINES | TRANSMISSION FLUIDS |
| CAPITAL CAB | LOWERCASE BUS |
| CAPITAL CABS | LOWERCASE BUSES |
| CAT CALLS | DOG WHISTLES |
| GOOD BOOK | BAD MOVIE |
| GOOD NUGGET | BAD EGG |
| HOBO TANGLER | JEEP WRANGLER |
| I LIKE | FLUFFY PANCAKES |
| KINDLE CARB | NOOK PROTEIN |
| KIT KAT | MILKY WAY |
| LARGE CAN | SMALL BOTTLE |
| LARGE JAB | SMALL PUNCH |
| MID MAID | MIDDLE MAIDS |
| MOO CAT | MEOW COW |
| MY WAYS | THE HIGHWAYS |
| SIT FAT | STAND THIN |
| SMALL MALL | BIG MALL |
| UPON THAT | UNDERNEATH THIS |
| ZORBA HUT | PIZZA HUTT |

CSV version:

```
Closely Capital Phrases™,Not Closely Capital Phrases™
BEARD COM,MUSTACHE DRAMA
BRAKE LINES,TRANSMISSION FLUIDS
CAPITAL CAB,LOWERCASE BUS
CAPITAL CABS,LOWERCASE BUSES
CAT CALLS,DOG WHISTLES
GOOD BOOK,BAD MOVIE
GOOD NUGGET,BAD EGG
HOBO TANGLER,JEEP WRANGLER
I LIKE,FLUFFY PANCAKES
KINDLE CARB,NOOK PROTEIN
KIT KAT,MILKY WAY
LARGE CAN,SMALL BOTTLE
LARGE JAB,SMALL PUNCH
MID MAID,MIDDLE MAIDS
MOO CAT,MEOW COW
MY WAYS,THE HIGHWAYS
SIT FAT,STAND THIN
SMALL MALL,BIG MALL
UPON THAT,UNDERNEATH THIS
ZORBA HUT,PIZZA HUTT
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption that each phrase can be tested for whether it is a Closely Capital Phrase™ without relying on the other phrases.  These are not the only examples of Closely Capital Phrases™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these phrases conform to?**

---

Added the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag because completely figuring this out will require an external resource for most people.  "Most people" is a guess on my part because I find it highly unlikely that a large number of people would just know the related info.

Hint 0 (from the comments):

> A Closely Capital Phrase™ must consist of exactly two words.

Hint 1:

> Swapping the word order of a Closely Capital Phrase™ will likely make it a Not Closely Capital Phrase™.

Hint 2:

> The phrase that Lord Harold Samuel is (perhaps incorrectly) credited with coining is relevant.

Hint 3:

> That short-lived NBC TV show that started in October of 2014, what was it called? I'm almost positive it's *1 to 26*.

Comment: Can a Closely Capital Phrase™ consist of more than two words?

Comment: @micsthepick, nope.

Comment: I think it has something to do with *isocolon* or *cola* I am not able to connect all the dots though

Comment: @Techidiot, the phrase that hint #2 refers to is indeed an isocolon, but the word isocolon itself (and cola for that matter) isn't relevant to the puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Closely Capital Phrase™ is a phrase ...

> ... of two words, whose A-to-Z sums, when taken as latitude and longitude, describe a location close to a national capital. It is not clear whether the latitudes are north or south ot whether the longitudes are east or west, so all four possibilities must be checked.

Evidence section:

> BEARD COM       — [30, 31](http://www.google.com/maps/@30.0,31.0,8z)      — Cairo, Egypt
>  BRAKE LINES     — [37, 59](http://www.google.com/maps/@37.0,59.0,8z)      — Ashgabat, Turkmenistan
>  CAPITAL CAB     — [62,  6](http://www.google.com/maps/@62.0,-6.0,8z)       — Torshavn, Faroe Islands (W)
>  CAPITAL CABS    — [62, 25](http://www.google.com/maps/@62.0,25.0,8z)      — Helsinki, Finland
>  CAT CALLS       — [24, 47](http://www.google.com/maps/@24.0,47.0,8z)      — Riyad, Saudi Arabia
>  GOOD BOOK       — [41, 43](http://www.google.com/maps/@41.0,43.0,8z)      — Tblisi, Georgia or Yerevan, Armenia
>  GOOD NUGGET     — [41, 74](http://www.google.com/maps/@41.0,74.0,8z)      — Bishkek, Kyrgyzstan
>  HOBO TANGLER    — [40, 77](http://www.google.com/maps/@40.0,-77.0,8z)     — Washington DC, U.S.A. (W)
>  I LIKE          — [9,  37](http://www.google.com/maps/@9.0,37.0,8z)        — Addis Ababa, Ethiopia
>  KINDLE CARB     — [55, 24](http://www.google.com/maps/@55.0,24.0,8z)      — Vilnius, Lithuania
>  KIT KAT         — [40, 32](http://www.google.com/maps/@40.0,32.0,8z)      — Ankara, Turkey
>  LARGE CAN       — [43, 18](http://www.google.com/maps/@43.0,18.0,8z)      — Sarajevo, Bosnia and Herzegovina
>  LARGE JAB       — [43, 13](http://www.google.com/maps/@43.0,13.0,8z)      — San Marino, San Marino
>  MID MAID        — [26, 27](http://www.google.com/maps/@-26.0,27.0,8z)     — Johanesburg, South Africa (S)
>  MOO CAT         — [43, 24](http://www.google.com/maps/@43.0,24.0,8z)      — Sofia, Bulgaria
>  MY WAYS         — [38, 68](http://www.google.com/maps/@38.0,68.0,8z)      — Dushanbe, Tajikistan
>  SIT FAT         — [48, 27](http://www.google.com/maps/@48.0,27.0,8z)      — Chisinau, Moldova
>  SMALL MALL      — [57, 38](http://www.google.com/maps/@57.0,38.0,8z)      — Moscow, Russia
>  UPON THAT       — [66, 49](http://www.google.com/maps/@66.0,-49.0,8z)     — Nuuk, Greenland (W)
>  ZORBA HUT       — [62, 49](http://www.google.com/maps/@62.0,49.0,8z)      — (I couldn't find anything here and I'm not sure about Nuuk above)
>
>  I haven't checked any of the Non Closely Capital Phrases. I'm lazy.

What do the hints mean?

> The NBC TV show is A to Z, which hints at the A to Z sum, i.e. summing the letter values of all letters in a word where A is 1, B is 2, C is 3 and so on. Lord Harold Samuel's phrase is "Location, location, location!", which hints at the use of the sums as latitude and longitude. And, of course, this use means that each phrase must have exactly two words.

Comment: Nicely done.  Thanks for not checking the Not Closely Capital Phrases™ as I'd rather not know if I made a mistake during the tedious process of creating this.  :P  $\qquad$  For the record, I used [this link](http://www.csgnetwork.com/llinfotable.html) to build the list and completely ignored N,S,E,W.

Comment: **SPOILER ALERT** Oh, and ZORBA HUT was also for Nuuk.  Officially my process was "round to the nearest degree and get a word score no more than $2$ off of the rounded value."  UPON THAT also satisfies that, barely.  There may have been a few that ended up being $3$ off, but I'm almost positive there aren't any $4$ or more.