# Someone's hiding

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Someone is hiding behind this montage! Can you find who?
The 5 images matter!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The person who is hiding is

> [James "Jimmie" Guthrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmie_Guthrie)

The images:

> - Top left circuit is the [Sachsenring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachsenring)
>  - The motorcycle is a Norton V4 RR
>  - Bottom right contains a picture of a very specific part of the [Isle of Man TT track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Man_TT) and a picture of [Fred Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Guy).
>  - (credits to [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)) The background shot is a promo from the movie [Kramer vs Kramer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramer_vs._Kramer)

The connections between these:

> Jimmie Guthrie was racing for the Norton Team, participated 12 times in the IOMTT (won 6 of them), and died in a crash on the Sachsenring. In the background of the IOMTT picture you can see [one of his memorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guthrie%27s_Memorial,_Isle_of_Man).
>  (credits to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm)) Guthrie and Guy share the same birthdate: May 23, 1897. Furthermore,  Jimmie Guthrie died on the day Dustin Hoffman (actor of Ted Kramer) was born

If you upvote this,

> may I suggest also upvoting some of Stiv and M Oehm's content to thank them for their contributions. [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111628/an-unusual-source-of-inspiration) are [some](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51698/what-is-a-closely-capital-phrase/51872#51872) of their posts you may have missed.

Comment: The background shot is a promo from the movie rot13(Xenzre if Xenzre) but I don't know why...

Comment: The connection to the man in the lower right corner is rot13(gurve pbzzba oveguqnl).

Comment: Hey, the rep donation scheme works. Thanks. `:)` As for the bg image: rot13(Wvzzvr Thguevr qvrq ba gur qnl Qhfgva Ubsszna jnf obea)

Comment: +3 for the three of you ;)

Comment: _Technically_ the rep donation scheme is against the site's rules. We don't have a better way of doing this kind of thing, unfortunately.